# function does not return a list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a function which is intended to output scraped elements from the website. However, when I try to use the function later in my script, the output is empty. Relevant sample of code below:

```
 def main(self):

    links = [a, b, c]
    self.soup_items = get_soup_items(links)      

 def get_soup_items(self, links):

    item_list = []
    for link in links:
        browser = webdriver.Chrome("path_to_chromedriver", chrome_options=chrome_options)
        browser.get(link)
        time.sleep(3)
        page_req = browser.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page_req, "html.parser")
        soupitems = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "content"})
        item_list.apppend(soupitems)

    return item_list


def get_objects(self):

    for item in self.soup_items:
             item_1 = item.find("span", {"class": "a"})
             print(item_1)
```

The desired output is for the get_soup_items to return soupitems. However, In the get objects function, when I try to iterate over the get_soup_items output I get an empty result.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
You haven't demonstrated that you actually have anything to add to that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for link in links:
    browser = webdriver.Chrome("path_to_chromedriver", chrome_options=chrome_options)
    browser.get(link)
    time.sleep(3)
    page_req = browser.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_req, "html.parser")
    soupitems = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "content"})
    item_list = item_list + soupitems
```

Your code never adds anything to the item_list so either you are not getting into the for loop, or soupitems is none.

Because of this

```
   for item in self.soup_items:
             item_1 = item.find("span", {"class": "a"})
             print(item_1)
```

your for each loop will not run because there are no items in self.soup_items.